# How to define and handle custom pragma #mypragma in Clang and LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, pragma

I want to allow compilation of my own pragma in C/Cpp files such as #pragma mypragma and I want to handle it in this way -- upon identification of this pragma, I want to insert a function call and delete some code in the original source file.

My problem is defining pragma and to handle it for inserting a function call. It would be great if someone can guide or suggest some tutorials. I am referring following resources but being newbie in front-end parsing, it is little hard. So, any help is highly appreciated. Thank you! :)

Resources that I am following are --
http://wvanteijlingen.github.io/notes/clang_pragmas
http://llvm.org/devmtg/2013-04/pellegrini-slides.pdf

Comment: Did u figure it out?

Comment: Yes. I followed the inbuilt loop-unroll pass.